# A constraint Voilation occured . While adding a user to Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

i have an OU named Users i am trying to add a User but this error occure's "A constraint voilation occured " 
My OU an CN is fine because recently it was working here is my create function

```
public static void CreateNewUser(string clientUpnSuffix, NewUserModel user)
    {
        if (!(Settings.IsLive))
        {
            return;
        }

        var clientDE = GetClientAccount(clientUpnSuffix).DirectoryEntry;
        var usersOUDE = clientDE.Children.Find("OU=Users");
        var userDE = usersOUDE.Children.Add("CN=" + user.UserName, "user");
        userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.USERPRINCIPALNAME].Value = string.Format("{0}@{1}", user.UserName, clientUpnSuffix);
        userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.SAMACCOUNTNAME].Value = user.UserName;

        userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.TELEPHONE].Value = user.Telephone;
        userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.OFFICE].Value = user.Department;
        userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.GIVENNAME].Value = user.FirstName;
        userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.SN].Value = user.LastName;

        userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.DISPLAYNAME].Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.FirstName, user.LastName);

        if (user.CreateMSExchangeAccount)
        {
            userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.MAIL].Value = string.Format("{0}@{1}", user.UserName, clientUpnSuffix);
        }
        else
        {
            userDE.Properties[ADAttribute.MAIL].Value = null;
        }

        //userDE.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { user.Password });

        userDE.CommitChanges();
        usersOUDE.Close();
        userDE.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [existing attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and not just the one your are dreaming of. As far as I remember 'TELEPHONE' should be `telephoneNumber` and 'OFFICE' may be `department`. This should be astarting point for your *constraint voilation*.